# Nested Select Statement on LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having an issue with the filtering my table F0005 properly. I have tried this query many different ways. What I want to accomplish is having the F0005 filtered before I join it.

This is how I want it filtered and the results are perfect on just that table.

```
SELECT LTRIM(F0005.DRKY), F0005.DRDL01, F0005.DRRT, F0005.DRSY
    FROM
            SENCOM.F0005 F0005
            WHERE LTRIM(F0005.DRKY) != '' AND F0005.DRRT IN ('W1','08') AND F0005.DRSY NOT IN ('30','32','98')
```

Here is my whole query and my attempt at filtering the table before joining it.

```
SELECT
    FSALES2011.SXAN8,
    FSALES2011.SXCO   AS Company,
    FSALES2011.SXMCU  AS BuisinessUnit,
    FSALES2011.SXLITM AS ItemNumber,
    FSALES2011.SXSLSM AS SalesPersonCode,
    FSALES2011.SXDCTO AS OrderType,
    FSALES2011.SXSLD1 AS SoldTo,
    FSALES2011.SXADD1 AS Address,
    FSALES2011.SXRP01 AS Division,
    FSALES2011.SXRP02 AS Location,
    FSALES2011.SXCI13+FSALES2011.SXCI14+FSALES2011.SXCI15+FSALES2011.SXCI16+FSALES2011.SXCI17+
    FSALES2011.SXCI18+FSALES2011.SXCI19+FSALES2011.SXCI20+FSALES2011.SXCI21+FSALES2011.SXCI22+
    FSALES2011.SXCI23+FSALES2011.SXCI24 AS PurchasePrice,
    FSALES2011.SXAS13+FSALES2011.SXAS14+FSALES2011.SXAS15+FSALES2011.SXAS16+FSALES2011.SXAS17+
    FSALES2011.SXAS18+FSALES2011.SXAS19+FSALES2011.SXAS20+FSALES2011.SXAS21+FSALES2011.SXAS22+
    FSALES2011.SXAS23+FSALES2011.SXAS24 AS SalesPrice,
    F4801.WAAN8,
    F4801.WAWR01         AS WoType,
    DIGITS(F4801.WADOCO) AS F4801ItemNumber,
    F0101.ABAN8,
    F0101.ABAC15              AS F0101CustomerType,
    F0006.MCRP08              AS JobType,
    SUBSTR(F0006.MCMCU,6,7)   AS F0006BuisnessUnit,
    LTRIM(F0005Filtered.DRKY) AS UDC,
    F0005Filtered.DRDL01      AS Description,
    F0005Filtered.DRRT,
    F0005Filtered.DRSY
  FROM
    SENDTA.F0101 F0101
  JOIN
    JDEMOD.FSALES2011 FSALES2011
  ON
    FSALES2011.SXAN8 = F0101.ABAN8
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    SENDTA.F0006 F0006
  ON
    FSALES2011.SXLITM = SUBSTR(F0006.MCMCU,6,7)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    SENDTA.F4801 F4801
  ON
    FSALES2011.SXLITM = DIGITS(F4801.WADOCO)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            LTRIM(F0005.DRKY),
            F0005.DRDL01,
            F0005.DRRT,
            F0005.DRSY
            FROM
            SENCOM.F0005 F0005
        WHERE
            LTRIM(F0005.DRKY) != ''
        AND F0005.DRRT IN ('W1',
                           '08')
        AND F0005.DRSY NOT IN ('30',
                               '32',
                               '98')) F0005Filtered
  ON
    ABAC15 = F0005Filtered.DRKY
```

When I try this I get Column errors, SQL0205] Column DRKY not in table F0005FILTERED in *N.

Thanks for any help I am kind of new to this and running out of ideas!! :)

Huge Thanks to Everyone, my problem was the formatting of my nested select but also something totally different. I was joining on the wrong field, so there were no matches and thats why i was getting the NULLs! thanks again!!

Here is the final version. Id be open to some optimization suggestions. Otherwise glad its done!

```
    SELECT
    FSALES2011.SXAN8,
    FSALES2011.SXCO   AS Company,
    FSALES2011.SXMCU  AS BuisinessUnit,
    FSALES2011.SXLITM AS ItemNumber,
    FSALES2011.SXSLSM AS SalesPersonCode,
    FSALES2011.SXDCTO AS OrderType,
    FSALES2011.SXSLD1 AS SoldTo,
    FSALES2011.SXADD1 AS Address,
    FSALES2011.SXRP01 AS Division,
    FSALES2011.SXRP02 AS Location,
    FSALES2011.SXCI13+FSALES2011.SXCI14+FSALES2011.SXCI15+FSALES2011.SXCI16+FSALES2011.SXCI17+
    FSALES2011.SXCI18+FSALES2011.SXCI19+FSALES2011.SXCI20+FSALES2011.SXCI21+FSALES2011.SXCI22+
    FSALES2011.SXCI23+FSALES2011.SXCI24 AS PurchasePrice,
    FSALES2011.SXAS13+FSALES2011.SXAS14+FSALES2011.SXAS15+FSALES2011.SXAS16+FSALES2011.SXAS17+
    FSALES2011.SXAS18+FSALES2011.SXAS19+FSALES2011.SXAS20+FSALES2011.SXAS21+FSALES2011.SXAS22+
    FSALES2011.SXAS23+FSALES2011.SXAS24 AS SalesPrice,
    F4801.WAAN8,
    F4801.WAWR01         AS WoType,
    DIGITS(F4801.WADOCO) AS F4801ItemNumber,
    F0101.ABAN8,
    F0101.ABAC15            AS F0101CustomerType,
    F0006.MCRP08            AS JobType,
    SUBSTR(F0006.MCMCU,6,7) AS F0006BuisnessUnit,
    LTRIM(UDC.DRKY)         AS Code,
    --UDC.DRDL01              AS JobDescription,
    --UDC2.DRDL01             AS WODescription,
    COALESCE(UDC.DRDL01,UDC2.DRDL01) AS WorkPerformed,
    UDC3.DRDL01                      AS CustomerDescription
FROM
    SENDTA.F0101 F0101
JOIN
    JDEMOD.FSALES2011 FSALES2011
ON
    FSALES2011.SXAN8 = F0101.ABAN8
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    SENDTA.F0006 F0006
ON
    FSALES2011.SXLITM = SUBSTR(F0006.MCMCU,6,7)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    SENDTA.F4801 F4801
ON
    FSALES2011.SXLITM = DIGITS(F4801.WADOCO)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    SENCOM.F0005 UDC
ON
    F0006.MCRP08 = LTRIM(UDC.DRKY)
AND LTRIM(UDC.DRKY) != ''
AND UDC.DRRT IN ('W1',
                 '08')
AND UDC.DRSY NOT IN ('30',
                     '32',
                     '98')
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    SENCOM.F0005 UDC2
ON
    F4801.WAWR01 = LTRIM(UDC2.DRKY)
AND LTRIM(UDC2.DRKY) != ''
AND UDC2.DRRT IN ('W1',
                  '08')
AND UDC2.DRSY NOT IN ('30',
                      '32',
                      '98')
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    SENCOM.F0005 UDC3
ON
    F0101.ABAC15 = LTRIM(UDC3.DRKY)
AND LTRIM(UDC3.DRKY) != ''
AND UDC3.DRRT IN ('15')
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding the AS allows its to run, my issue now is its not doing what i wanted it to! what is happening is F0005 has descriptions for some codes  in one of the other tables. When I do this join, all of the descriptions are NULL.

Comment: Step through your query one piece at a time.  By starting with a small query, then adding joins, you can see at which point the unsual behaviour occures.  That join is the one you need to investigate.  Are the values in the fields the values that you expect?  (For example, when you join ABAC15 to LTRIM(DRKY), have you checked that there are actually any matches, perhaps you need to LTRIM(ABAC15) as well?

Comment: @jcervantes you say that the descriptions are NULL, are you sure there are descriptions for the records you are joining on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you wrap a field in a function, you need to name it afterwards.

Change `LTRIM(F0005.DRKY),` to `LTRIM(F0005.DRKY) AS DRKY,`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer! Any idea why I would be bringing over all the null values? What would be a good way to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 6):

In your nested query you are missing the alias for DRKY:

```
SELECT
            LTRIM(F0005.DRKY) as DRKY,
            F0005.DRDL01,
            F0005.DRRT,
            F0005.DRSY
            FROM SENCOM.F0005 F0005
        WHERE LTRIM(F0005.DRKY) != ''
        AND F0005.DRRT IN ('W1',
                           '08')
        AND F0005.DRSY NOT IN ('30',
                               '32',
                               '98')) F0005Filtered
```

If you don't have an alias when it return no column name for the `LTRIM(F0005.DRKY)`

Answer (score 6):

You need to be naming your computed columns in your filtered table.

```
SELECT LTRIM(F0005.DRKY) AS DRKY, F0005.DRDL01, F0005.DRRT, F0005.DRSY
FROM SENCOM.F0005 F0005
WHERE LTRIM(F0005.DRKY) != '' 
   AND F0005.DRRT IN ('W1','08') 
   AND F0005.DRSY NOT IN ('30','32','98')
```

Note that `AS DRKY`

Answer (score 3):

You really need to reformat your question, but I believe I know where you have gone wrong.

Your table alias, F0005Filtered, is not an alias on the JDE user-defined codes table.  You have created a sub-select which is what F0005Filtered actually represents.

Further, inside that sub-select, you have no column called DRKY.

You are using the TRIM function on that field and not specifying a column name.

To fix, simply recreate the alias:-

```
LTRIM(F0005.DRKY) AS DRKY
```

**EDIT**

In response to user question.

Why not make your IN statements part of the JOIN condition?

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    SENCOM.F0005 UDC
ON  LTRIM(UDC.DRKY) != ''
AND ABAC15 = TRIM(UDC.DRKY)
AND UDC.DRRT IN ('W1','08')
AND UDC.DRSY NOT IN ('30', '32','98')
```

User-defined code tables tend not to be that large.  I do some work for a major multinational and ours has around 70K rows.

Comment: You seem to be familiar with the data I am working with! Any ideas for improvement. Have you done anything similar?

Comment: Yes, I'm rather familiar with JDE.  It varies from Enterprise to Enterprise.  Personally, I pull the whole table down when I have a serious need ( it is very useful ).

I guess I'm not getting why you need the UDC table as a subselect.

Comment: Sure, ill explain. I Have my FSALES which is a custom table with sales data. I join my F0101 and F4801 because they have the Job Type Code and Customer Type Code. F0005 has my descriptions for the codes. so I want to join that so people don't have to look them up. My problem is F0005 seems to have a lot more than just UDC data for the info I need. So when I do a left join it brings over a lot of extra data. ON F0101.ABAC15 = F0005.DRKY my rows go from 70000 to about 300000 because there are a lot of duplicates in DRKY.